# Does something need to be running on the EC2 for it to pass Health Checks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Okay this may seem like a dumb question but I have to say I'm a little stumped. I can't figure out why my ELB (Classic) --> EC2 health checks are failing in AWS.

So the way I have things configured, my ELB's health checks will try to ping the instance on `TCP:8080`.

I have 3 port listeners on my ELB, which from my understanding shouldn't matter because that deals with traffic originating externally but I'll list that just in case I'm overlooking something:
1.) `HTTP:80 --> HTTP:8080`
2.) `HTTPS:443 --> HTTP:8080`
3.) `TCP:2222 --> TCP:2222`

I've also tried to configure the health checks to ping `TCP:2222` just in case and same deal..

Additionally, I've got Security groups for my EC2 that enable `TCP:8080` and `TCP:2222` from my ELB's Security Group.

Is the reason it's failing because while the EC2 instance allows the traffic, it still needs something to be running on that port to serve the traffic?

All the EC2 is currently is a simple AWS supplied Linux AMI.

Forgive me I'm a little new to the networking space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes something needs to be running on the server. If there is no process running on the server, listening for and responding to requests on port `8080`, then the health check will fail. You would want the health check to fail if your software running on your server crashed wouldn't you? An instance isn't "healthy" if it isn't responding to requests.

Also, the security group assigned to the EC2 instance needs to be configured to allow incoming traffic on those ports (`8080` and `2222`) originating from the ELB.

Comment: Not only did you answer my question, but you explained a case why health checks are configured the way they are. Thanks Mark!